# convert difftime time to years, months and days

Tags: r

How can I accurately convert the products (units is in days) of the `difftime` below to years, months and days?

```
difftime(Sys.time(),"1931-04-10")
difftime(Sys.time(),"2012-04-10")
```

This does years and days but how could I include months?

```
yd.conv<-function(days, print=TRUE){
    x<-days*0.00273790700698851
    x2<-floor(x)
    x3<-x-x2
    x4<-floor(x3*365.25)
    if (print) cat(x2,"years &",x4,"days\n")
    invisible(c(x2, x4))
}

yd.conv(difftime(Sys.time(),"1931-04-10"))
yd.conv(difftime(Sys.time(),"2012-04-10"))
```

I'm not sure how to even define months either.  Would 4 weeks be considered a month or the passing of the same month day.  So for the later definition of a month if the initial date was 2012-01-10 and the current 2012-05-31 then we'd have 0 years, 5 months and 21 days.  This works well but what if the original date was on the 31st of the month and the end date was on feb 28 would this be considered a month?

**As I wrote this question the question itself evolved so I'd better clarify:**

***What would be the best (most logical approach) to defining months and then how to find diff time in years, months and days?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're doing something like

```
difftime(Sys.time(), someDate)
```

It comes as implied that you must know what *someDate* is. In that case, you can convert this to a POSIXct class object that gives you the ability to extract temporal information directly (package *chron* offers more methods, too). For instance

```
as.POSIXct(c(difftime(Sys.time(), someDate, units = "sec")), origin = someDate)
```

This will return your desired date object. If you have a timezone tz to feed into difftime, you can also pass that directly to the tz parameter in as.POSIXct.

Now that you have your date object, you can run things like `months(.)` and if you have chron you can do `years(.)` and `days(.)` (returns ordered factor).

From here, you could do more simple math on the difference of years, months, and days separately (converting to appropriate numeric representations). Of course, convert *someDate* to POSIXct will be required.

EDIT: On second thought, `months(.)` returns a character representation of the month, so that may not be efficient. At least, it'll require a little processing (not too difficult) to give a numeric representation.

Comment: Thinking about it now, (1) You could just convert a current Sys.time() to a POSIX class object and the someDate to a POSIX object (or just date object) and work from there. The approach above is a bit superfluous in this regard. (2) I'm unsure if you want results to be like 3 years and 2 months and 7 days or if you want separate total accounts like 3 years | 38 months | X days. In any case, years is immediate, total months can be easily calculated, and days is the result from c(difftime(.)) or other possible time arithmetic.

Comment: Also, when dealing with dates and times, a good rule to follow is: if you're only concerned with dates, use a Date class object. If you're concerned with time, but not specifics (e.g., timezone), use a chron class object. Otherwise, you want all the details, so use POSIXlt or POSIXct (the former is stored as a list). The time methods tend to work on all these objects.

Answer (score 1):

R has not implemented these features out of ignorance. `difftime` objects are transitive. A 700 day difference on any arbitrary start-date can yield a differing number of years depending on whether there was a leap year or not. Similarly for months, they take between 28-31 days.

For research purposes, we use these units a lot (months and years) and pragmatically, we define a year as 365.25 days and a month as 365.25/12 = 30.4375 days.

To do arithmetic on a given difftime, you must convert this value to numeric  using `as.numeric(difftime.obj)` which is, in default, days so R stops spouting off the units.

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply convert a difftime to month, since the definition of months depends on the absolute time at which the difftime has started.

You'll need to know the start date or the end date to accurately tell the number of months.

You could then, e.g., calculate the number of months in the first year of your timespan, the number of month in the last your of the timespan, and add the number of years between times 12.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I think the most sensible would be to look at the various units themselves. So compare the day of the month first, then compare the month of the year, then compare the year. At each point, you can introduce a carry to avoid negative values.

In other words, don't work with the product of difftime, but recode your own difftime.

Comment: `difftime` takes into account leap years though.

Comment: @TylerRinker but as both answerers allude to, displaying `# years # months # days` looses some accuracy anyway. So why not just take that hit and do rough math on the dates using a custom `difftime` function?  Since you're already losing some precision, you could do something like the average number of days in a month and just add that portion to your current function.

Comment: I think it's more intuitive anyway to have e.g. 1/1/2012 and 1/1/2013 give a difference of exactly one year, than give the result 1 year and 1 day, or worse, 1 year and 0.25 days.