# Extending difftime() to include months and years

Tags: r

I can get the time since `x` with `difftime`, but only up to week intervals.

```
> difftime(Sys.Date(), "1977-04-05")
# Time difference of 13655.67 days
> difftime(Sys.Date(), "1977-04-05", units = "weeks")
# Time difference of 1950.81 weeks
```

Other than calculating it manually, is there a function to get the months and years since `x`?

I've looked at this question [convert difftime time to years, months and days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836503/convert-difftime-time-to-years-months-and-days), but it was asked and answered over two years ago and I thought there may be some new stuff out there now.

The reason I'd like to get this information is to add it to this useless function

```
> timeSinceBirth <- function(dob) 
  {
      today <- Sys.Date()
      s <- sapply(list(NULL, "weeks"), function(x) {
          difftime(today, dob, units = x)
      })
      setNames(s, c("days", "weeks"))
  }
> timeSinceBirth("1977-04-05")
#     days    weeks 
# 13655.67  1950.81
```

I'd like the result to have `months` and `years` included after `weeks`

Comment: How long is a month/year? They have variable lengths unlike week/day/hour etc.. The output from difftime is a scalar I think month/year would require a vector

Comment: I was thinking something like `month` from `lubridate` since it takes that into account already, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a sequence. So something like:

```
timeSinceBirth <- function(dob) 
{
  today <- Sys.Date()
  s <- sapply(list("days", "weeks", "months", "years"), function(x) {
    (length(seq(as.Date(dob), Sys.Date(), x)) - 1)
  })
  setNames(s, c("days", "weeks", "months", "years"))
}

> timeSinceBirth("1977-04-05")
days  weeks months  years 
13657   1951    448     37
```