# Difference between dates in years-months-days format

Tags: r

I'm trying to replicate what this [website](https://www.calculator.net/date-calculator.html?today=09%2F17%2F1985&ageat=03%2F13%2F1996&calctype=diff&x=103&y=3) does - get difference between 2 dates expressed in years-months-days.

I managed to get years-months difference in pretty dirty way:

```
paste(
  floor(
    interval(as.Date("1985-09-17"),
             as.Date("1996-03-13")) 
        %/% months(1) /12), ' years, ',
      ifelse(
        ceiling(((interval(as.Date("1985-09-17"),
                           as.Date("1996-03-13")) 
                 %/% months(1) /12) %% 1 )*12)<10,
         paste0('0',ceiling(((interval(as.Date("1985-09-17"),
                                       as.Date("1996-03-13")) 
                             %/% months(1) /12) %% 1)*12)),
          ceiling(((interval(as.Date("1985-09-17"),
                             as.Date("1996-03-13")) 
                   %/% months(1) /12) %% 1 )*12)),' months', sep='')



[1] "10 years, 04 months"
```

Is there a better way to do this? I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836503/convert-difftime-time-to-years-months-and-days) but it doesn't have satisfying answer and I'm guessing many new packages been developed since then, so maybe there is a simple way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like the following:

```
as.Date(as.numeric(as.Date("1996-03-13"))
        -as.numeric(as.Date("1985-09-17")), 
        origin = "2000-01-01")
```

and then read the years months and days starting from the origin as your difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and this worked for me:

First get the difftime in days, then divide over 365.25 days per year and keep the integer value to get the number of years.

Then keep the decimal part and multiply by 12 to get the number of months.

To get the number of days, you want to keep the decimal part after you get the number of months and multiply by 365.25/12.

```
paste(as.integer(difftime("1996-03-13", "1985-09-17")/365.25), "years",
      as.integer(as.numeric(difftime("1996-03-13", "1985-09-17")/365.25)%%1 * 12), "months",
      as.integer((as.numeric(difftime("1996-03-13", "1985-09-17")/365.25)%%1 * 12)%%1 * 365.25/12), "days")

[1] "10 years 5 months 25 days"
```

If you prefer to work with library(lubridate):

```
paste(as.integer(time_length(interval("1985-09-17", "1996-03-13"), "days")/365.25), "years", 
      as.integer((time_length(interval("1985-09-17", "1996-03-13"), "days")/365.25)%%1 * 12), "months",
      as.integer(((time_length(interval("1985-09-17", "1996-03-13"), "days")/365.25)%%1 * 12)%%1 * 365.25/12), "days")
```